# How to update panel by doing action from panel grid in jsf

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Trying to update panel by clicking button from another panelgrid.but not working

```
     <h:panelGrid columns="3"  id="qualaddpanelgrid12">
                <p:selectOneMenu value="#{qualCntrl.qualificationGroup}"  id="qualificationGroup"  style="width:180px;" disabled="#{qualCntrl.dropDownEnable}">  
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Please Select" Value="P" />  
                <f:selectItems itemLabel="#{qualCntrl.qualificationGroupList()}" value="#{qualCntrl.qualificationGroupList()}" />  
                </p:selectOneMenu>   
                &nbsp; 
                <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-plus" actionListener="#{qualCntrl.enableGroupPanel}"  update="qualaddpanelgrid12,groupPanel" ></p:commandButton>
<p:panel id="groupPanel" header="Add New Group"  closable="true"   widgetVar="groupPanel" style="width:170px;" rendered="#{qualCntrl.groupPanelEnable}">
         </p:panel>
```

groupPanel is not updating.

Comment: post full code and explain what is not working.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you problem is that your panel wont appear on the screen. 
The cause of this is that you can't update a component which is not rendered. You have to put your p:panel into another p:panel (or any container component) and update the outer component.
e.g.:

```
<p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-plus" actionListener="#{qualCntrl.enableGroupPanel}"  update="qualaddpanelgrid12,updateMe" />
<p:panel id="updateMe">
    <p:panel id="groupPanel" header="Add New Group"  closable="true"   widgetVar="groupPanel" style="width:170px;" rendered="#{qualCntrl.groupPanelEnable}"></p:panel>
</p:panel>
```